# Using Flutter on Linux with Snapcraft: dependency failure with Dart version, despite all parts being compatible

Tags: linux, flutter, snapcraft

Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.2.

Because workstatus depends on dependencies any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
Process finished with exit code 1

this is the issue i am facing after the 3.10 upgrade of flutter and dart version 3.0.2
perviously i was working on 3.7 flutter

I am trying to make snapcraft build for linux, and it's showing error of dart version

on local base code is showing same error, somewhat error says that any of the dependency used doesnt support dart 3 but the parts i have used are all supported by dart 3

this is the list

archive: ^3.3.6
bitsdojo_window: ^0.1.2
bot_toast: ^4.0.1
connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
convert: ^3.0.2
cron: ^0.5.1
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
current_location: ^0.0.3
data_table_2: ^2.3.5
date_format: ^1.0.8
datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0
dependencies:
desktop_lifecycle: ^0.1.0
desktop_multi_window: ^0.2.0
desktop_window: ^0.4.0
device_info_plus: ^4.0.0
dio: ^5.1.2
dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
dropdown_button2: ^1.5.1
equatable: any
ffi: ^1.0.0
file_picker: ^4.6.1
firebase_core:
flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
flutter_desktop_sleep: ^0.0.2
flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
flutter_image: ^4.1.5
flutter_isolate: ^2.0.4
flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0
flutter_luban: ^0.1.13
flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
flutter_platform_alert: ^0.3.0
flutter_to_debian: ^1.0.4
flutter_window_close: ^0.2.2
font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
get_it: ^7.2.0
google_fonts: ^3.0.1
hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
hive_listener: ^1.2.1
hive: ^2.2.3
http: ^0.13.4
image: ^3.0.8
in_app_notification: ^1.1.2
intl: ^0.17.0
json_annotation: ^4.3.0
json_serializable: ^6.3.1
jwt_decoder: ^2.0.1
launch_at_startup: ^0.2.2
loading_gifs: ^0.3.0
logger: ^1.1.0
minio:
multi_window: ^0.2.0
my_popup_menu: ^3.0.5
network_info_plus: ^2.1.4+1
nativeshell: ^0.1.16
package_info_plus:
path_provider:
path: ^1.8.0
process_run: ^0.12.3+2
provider:
quds_popup_menu: ^0.0.1+1
rxdart: ^0.27.5
screen_retriever: ^0.1.3
sentry_flutter: ^6.19.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
shell: ^2.0.0
system_tray: ^2.0.1
timer_builder: ^2.0.0
timezone_utc_offset: ^1.1.0
timezone: ^0.8.0
tray_manager: ^0.1.8
url_launcher: any
win_capture: ^0.0.3
win_tracker: ^0.0.6
window_manager: ^0.2.7
window_to_front: ^0.0.3
winhooker: ^0.0.3